# Twilio rest api is not returning in-progress calls with SIP

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am trying to get the live calls from the rest api. But it is always returning no calls. The Twilio number is connected with SIP.

Below is my PHP Code.

```
    $calls = $client->calls->read(array("status" => "in-progress"));
```

Comment: Do you mean the number is connected by SIP trunk? Or is it a call made with the TwiML `<Sip>`?

Comment: It is connected by SIP trunk. Completed calls has the direction trunking-originating, trunking-terminating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Calls made from or to your SIP trunks are not available from the REST API while they are in flight I'm afraid. You can find out information about SIP trunk calls once they are complete, just not during the call.

I'm trying to find documentation to describe this and if I can I will update this question. If I can't, I will create it and then update this question. Sorry you had to turn to SO to find this out.